# On existence of orthonormal basis for each subsystem in Separable state

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, quantum-information, density-operator

A separable state in $\mathcal{H}_{a}\otimes\mathcal{H}_{b}$ is given by

$$\rho_{s}=\sum_{\alpha,\beta}p(\alpha,\beta)|\alpha\rangle\!\langle\alpha|\otimes|\beta\rangle\!\langle\beta|.$$

Now, my question is, can what can we say about the existence of $\{|\alpha \rangle\}$ and $\{|\beta \rangle\}$ such that all of them are elements from a complete basis (non-unique) in individual subsystem? Whether they exist? or for what kind state they exists (for example, in case zero discord state-they exist, as pointed out by one of the commentators[1](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/18421/55))

A reason I think such a set of basis exist for all separable state is because separable state space is the convex hull of tesnor products of symmetric rank-$1$ projectors which are affinely independent (Caratheodory's theorem), thus by definifion, there exists a set of linearly independent vectors for each subsystem (mostly, nonunique), let's say those are $\{\alpha\rangle\}$ and $\{|\beta\rangle\}$. Surely, we can add few more vectors to both suitably to span the whole space!! Is it true? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: See Schmidt decomposition ,link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schmidt_decomposition

Comment: Isn't Schmidt decomposition work only for pure states?

Comment: You can use Schmidt decomposition technique to determine whether any given state is pure or not. Schmidt rank should be 1 for pure states

Comment: No, Schmidt rank $1$ means the state is product state, greater than $1$ means it is entangled. For example, maximally entangled state $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|00>+|11>)$ has Schmidt rank $2$.

Comment: Yeah correct, apologies for my mistake. Btw how did you define the $|\alpha\rangle$ and $|\beta\rangle$ kets?

Comment: Note that, $\alpha$ is the multi-index $(i,j)$ and $\beta$ is the multi-index $(i,k)$. and the vector $|j_{i}>$ is also identified with the pair $(i,j)$, thus we can replace $|i_{j}>$ with $|\alpha>$ and similarly for $|\beta>$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127393/discussion-between-winterfell-and-kp99).

Comment: The question is missing details. Are you asking whether this holds for SOME state rho? For ALL states RHO? For ANY such decomposition? For SOME such decomposition? Also, the title does not seem to match the question.

Comment: For all separable states, whether such a decomposition exists..?

Comment: @NorbertSchuch the title is partly my fault. The current one comes from my best understanding of OP's intended question, judging from the comments to the related post on qc.SE

Comment: @glS Hm, the question certainly seems to ask: I am doing a separable decomposition of rho using pure state, what properties will those pure states have. Seems rather different from the title. (And your answer over at qc.se also does not seem to be a counterexample to the title question.) -- BTW, one more reason against cross-posts: The clarifying comments only appear in one place.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch I edited the title, hopefully now it is clear.

Comment: @WInterfell This is not what your question seems to ask. There you give a concrete recipe -- which might include ambiguous choices -- and then ask whether this specific procedure gives a basis. (And, furthermore, in the question it does not become clear whether "basis" just means "chosen from a basis" or "complete basis". Complete is wrong, as can be seen from any pure product state.)

Comment: Gut feeling: The states you describe are states with zero quantum discord (i.e. not all separable states).

Comment: Okay, I understood, the procedure I mentioned only serves as a possible way to demonstrate change of variables, I have edited the suitable parts, let me know whether it makes sense now?

Comment: If the question really asks what the title asks, it would be much better off if you really only asked the question from the title with some details, rather than explaining how to get a decomposition into pure product states. How does it elucidate your question?

Comment: Oh! that makes much sense, to be honest, I was interested in how to find such a pure state decomposition also, that's the reason I gave the procedure, guess, but now I am content with the possible exitence of such a decomposition.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch I mostly agree. The answer there was posted before clarifications in the comments. @ Winterfell the current body of the question is much clearer, you should probably edit the version on qc.SE as well (or even better, just keep only one of the two versions, which makes everything easier to manage)

Comment: @gIS I couldn't deleate the question there, perhaps, we can close this here, then I will modify the question there.

Comment: @WInterfell sorry, I'm getting confused. I thought you said you wanted to delete the one on qc.SE not this one. If you want to close this one you can do it, just click on the "close" button underneath the question

Comment: Yeah, I want to close, the qc.SE one.

Comment: The question isn't super clear to me. But if you're asking whether the states $\{|\alpha\rangle\}$ in the decomposition you quote can be an orthonormal basis for the first half of the tensor product, you can kick-start your analysis by considering the eigenvector decomposition of the partial trace $\mathrm{Tr}_B(\rho)$. If your states $\{|\alpha\rangle\}$ are an orthonormal basis, they must coincide with the eigenbasis of $\mathrm{Tr}_B(\rho)$ (absent any degeneracies).

Comment: @EmilioPisanty For a separable state: $\rho=\sum_{x,y}p(x,y)|x><x|\otimes|y><y|$, the reduced density matrix of A w.r.t ONB $\{|b>\}$ is, $\rho_{A}=\sum_{x}p_{x}|x><x|$, now their eigenbasis is $\{|\alpha>\}$. Then we have a Unitary matrix, $U_{A}$ whose columns are orthonormal basis $\{|\alpha>\}$. We then have $U_{A}\rho_{A}U_{A}^{\dagger}=\Lambda_{A}$. Similar procedure fo $B$ would give $U_{B}\rho_{B}U_{B}^{\dagger}=\Lambda_{B}$., with $\{|\beta>\}$ being eigenbasis. Now, can we say that, there $\sum q_{\alpha,\beta}|\alpha><\alpha|\otimes|\beta><\beta|=\rho$?

Comment: @WInterfell You've missed the point. If $\rho=\sum_{\alpha,\beta}p(\alpha,\beta)|\alpha\rangle\!\langle\alpha|\otimes|\beta\rangle\!\langle\beta|$ and $\{|\alpha\rangle\}$ are orthonormal, then $\rho_{A}=\sum_{\alpha,\beta}p(\alpha,\beta)|\alpha\rangle\!\langle\alpha|$ is already in diagonal form and the $|\alpha\rangle$ are the eigenvectors of $\rho_A$. You don't need any unitary there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, such a decomposition does not always exist.

To see this, we need two facts:

(1) The set of all separable state has the same dimension as the set of all density operators (it is a finite-volume subset) -- that is, it has $\approx D^4$ real parameters (if both systems have dimension $D$).

(2) The family you descibe is fully specified by the $p$ ($\approx D^2$ parameters) and the basis choice for the two bases, which are given by a $D\times D$ unitary matrix (i.e. $\approx D^2$ real parameters) each, i.e., $\approx 3D^2$ parameters in total.

Thus, the ansatz you describe has by far not enough parameters to describe all separable states.

Comment: huh. Is there a way to get a sense of the type of states that are left stranded in this set difference?

Comment: @Emilio Any random separable state? -- More to the point, the issue is (intuitively) that for a basis $|\alpha\rangle$, $|\alpha\rangle\langle\alpha|$ is *not*  a basis of the space of operators. (This made me think immediately that this should not work.) You would have to use e.g. a SIC-POVM $|\alpha\rangle$. -- Based on this intuition, I would guess sth. like $|0\rangle\langle0|\otimes|0\rangle\langle0|+|+\rangle\langle+|\otimes|+\rangle\langle+|+|1\rangle\langle1\otimes |1\rangle\langle1|$ could be such an example.